# Is it okay to host a node that connects on the clearnet?

Tags: security, privacy, governance

There is some concern in regulatory bodies about governing Monero in the future. Does this have implications for people hosting nodes at home on personal computers and connecting on the clearnet, without a VPN? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to your local juridiction.
In most countries, running an application, as long as it does not break any existing laws, is totally legal.

If something change in the future, it might just be on the taxation of cryptocurrencies themselves.
Nodes owner may not be targeted by this taxation, or may be depending on your juridiction.

To summarize: look at your local laws to ensure your not breaking any (it's highly improbable you are) to run a node today, and stay tuned to your juridiction's new law to avoid breaking them.

But in the future, Kovri will be in General Availability release and integrated to Monero so that you shouldn't be seen by any juridiction.
This could help you to continue using the software in case of banishment, if regulators don't manage to apply a taxation model on secure cryptocurrencies.  That said, i would not push you to break any law.